# Instagram bot, Python, instaBot

Tags: python, request, instagram

I have a Python program that posts information in Instagram using the InstaBot.
Every night I try to run the code I have the following Error. ( Internet connection is ok)
But in the morning , everything is ok :)
Why? really why ?

```
from logging import exception
from instabot import Bot
import os
import shutil
import json
import instabot
import requests
import jdatetime
from datetime import datetime
import time
import random
.
.
.

clean_up(1)
bot = Bot()
while True :
    try: 
        bot.login(username = "****", 
            password = "****") 
        break
    except Exception as e: 
        print ('*****************login exception!**********************'+e)
        time.sleep(300)
.
.
.
```

problem:

> 2021-11-23 23:18:07,183 - WARNING -
> HTTPSConnectionPool(host='i.instagram.com', port=443): Max retries
> exceeded with url: /api/v1/launcher/sync/ (Caused by
> NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at
> 0x0000028E05C696A0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno
> 11001] getaddrinfo failed'))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thing that error from instagram is because you are using the exceeding a limit rate from a api